# How to mass update custom fields for more than 20k posts

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I have a picture gallery website I put together with various plugins and dirty file editing hacks. For example I had to make sure jetpack infinite scroll plays nice with theme's masonry and lazy loading of images which are read from a custom field! etc..

I grow tired of spending time on making sure plugins and hacks play to nice with each other, and I really want to be able to update my wordpress and plugins etc. So I created my own theme from scratch. I'm pretty sure my theme is ready to be deployed live. But there is one little problem.

I was using "Nelio External Featured Image" plugin, so all of my images are stored with its own custom field "_nelioefi_url". I want to change it to "external_thumbnail". For 20k posts. Before cloning the database offline and using mysql update commands, I wanted to ask if someone knows an easier way.

Comment: So, you want to replace every instance of `_nelioefi_url` with `external_thumbnail` in the *_postmeta table?

Comment: yes that is correct @codiiv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this and it works.

```
<?php 

function toCall(){
    global $wpdb;
    $togos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *   FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_nelioefi_url'");
    return $togos;
}

foreach (toCall() as $go) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
                $wpdb->postmeta,
                array(
                    'meta_key' => 'external_thumbnail', // string
                    // 'column2' => 'value2'    // integer (number)
                ),
                array( 'meta_id' => $go->meta_id )
            );
};  ?>
```

You can call the foreach loop somewhere in a file, just make sure you have enough memory :)

**EDIT** You can put everything in one function:

```
function toCall(){
    global $wpdb;
    $togos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_nelioefi_url'");


    foreach ($togos as $go) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update(
                    $wpdb->postmeta,
                    array(
                        'meta_key' => 'external_thumbnail', // string
                        // 'column2' => 'value2'    // integer (number)
                    ),
                    array( 'meta_id' => $go->meta_id )
                );
    };

}  ?>
```

Then you can call the `toCall()` method anywhere you want in a template, or otherwise.

**NB: The changes are irreversible. So, make sure you have backups.**